# The best way to get iPad Audio into my DAW?

Tags: ableton, ipad

I'm making music on a Mac and what I want to do is be able to record audio coming from my iPad into Ableton Live 10 via my Scarlett 18i20 audio interface. But I also want to be able to control the midi of Audio Units I have on my iPad via USB. Is this possible?

Currently, i'm MacOS's built-in "Audio Midi" setup to set up my iPad as an input device. The problem with this is that it's janky and Ableton doesn't always recognize the input, even when I use a multi-input aggregate.

Is there a better way go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I did my iPad through a DAW I used a 3.5mm TRS to 1/4” breakout cable to a DI box into the interface. Use two DI boxes for stereo input or set the iPad sound settings to mono.